# How do I deallocate this in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, nodes

I create a 2D array of `Nodes` (`Node` class is in a separate file) and i'm wondering how to deallocate exactly this (below). I've tried many ways and mem leaks still appear.

```
board = new Node * [r];

//creats a column for each element in the row
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    board [i] = new Node [c];
}
```

(`r` is the rows and `c` is the cols)

I've done this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {

    delete [] board[i];
}

delete [] board;
```

But apparently it's not enough

Comment: Is that really all I need to deallocate when I'm allocating with new?

Comment: Yes it is fine. The rule is "for every `new` you have a `delete`; for every `new[]`, you have a `delete[]`." And that checks out in this case. It may not be `exception safe` but the code itself is correct.

Comment: Who told you that you have memory leaks?

Comment: Valgrind.. after this code there's a nested for loop to create new nodes and then change those up... but I don't know how to get rid of those.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is correct and sufficient.  However, it would be better to use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) so that you do not need to explicitly call `delete` at all (perhaps not even `new`).  For example, you could create a `std::vector<std::vector<Node>>`, or better still, some sort of matrix class (not in the standard library, unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is the correct way to free two dimensional array.  However you may still get a memory leak if `Node` uses dynamic memory and it's destructor  is not properly defined.

Comment: What would I put in the Node destructor? I just set all the pointers that are located in it to null and "delete this". The pointers in the Node class are never used with "new", so not sure what i have to do.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing `delete this;`?

Comment: @LucasMarzocco Don't put `delete this` in the destructor! That would cause stack overflows (since your destructor calls itself) and heap corruption (since you're deleting something multiple times).

Comment: If there is no dynamic memory usage in Node you should be good to go.  Otherwise you need to free that memory in the destructor. Don't call `delete this`!

Comment: Ugh, valgrind wants to say otherwise :(((((

Comment: @LucasMarzocco Maybe you can post some code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you're correctly pairing up all your `new[]`s and `delete[]`s: assuming no errors occur, the memory allocated by this code will be correctly deallocated.

The only issue is that errors may occur, and in particular exceptions may be thrown:

- `new[]` can throw an exception if it fails to allocate memory (doesn't normally happen on desktop OSes, but you should still write code as if it does.)
- `Node`'s constructor may throw. Even if you've designed the constructor not to throw you generally shouldn't take advantage of that knowledge. Just write code as if throws.
- In fact, you should just generally write code as if pretty much anything can throw. For more detailed info on writing exception safe code, and on what the exceptions to this rule are you can read the info at http://exceptionsafecode.com

The best way to make this code exception safe is to use RAII. For example use a `vector` instead of `new[]`/`delete[]`.

---

Using an array of pointers and a separate allocation for each row makes sense for 'ragged' arrays, where each row can be a different length. In your case you have rectangular array, so you can use a single allocation for the whole thing.

```
std::vector<Node> board(rows*columns);

board[row_index*columns + column_index] // replaces board[row_index][column_index]
```

You can hide the implementation by putting this in a class:

```
class Board {
  std::vector<Node> board_data;
public:
  const int rows;
  const int columns;

  Board(int rows_, int columns_)
    : board_data(rows_*columns_)
    , rows(rows_)
    , columns(columns_)
  {}

  struct board_index { int row, column; };

  Node &operator[](board_index i) {
    assert(0 <= i.row && i.row < rows);
    assert(0 <= i.column && i.column < columns);
    return board_data[i.row * columns + i.column];
  }
};

Board board(r, c);
```

with the above implementation you replace `board[i][j]` with `board[{i, j}]`.

```
board[{i, j}] = ... // assign to a place on the board
board[{i, j}].foo(); // call a Node method
std::cout << board[{i, j}]; // print a Node
// etc.
```